Connection timeouts when connecting to lambda from inside pod, but not from ec2?
I have a lambda function running on AWS. It exposes an API endpoint.
Inside my VPC, there is an EKS cluster and there are a few EC2 instances. The same Java code runs inside pods on the cluster and on the EC2 instances. The code sends an HTTP POST request to the endpoint of the lambda function.
The problem is, when pods try to establish a TCP connection to lambda, there are often connection timeouts and I need to keep trying a few times for it to succeed. This happens especially after the pod is idle for some time (no HTTP requests coming and going). Also, at the same time, some pods are able to connect while others aren't.
EC2 instances don't have this problem, even though they are running the same Java code, call the same lambda endpoint, and have similar computational resources with pods. They reside in the same VPC with the EKS cluster.
The EKS cluster has CNI plugin and "security groups for pods" enabled. The connection to lambda works time to time, if it didn't work at all I'd be suspicious of a misconfiguration.
What can cause this type of behaviour? Is there some outgoing TCP connection limit on the EKS cluster nodes?
